Finding best convex approximation to piecewise linear fucntion
I am given some function $g: [0,1] -> R$ which is piecewise linear (and continuous) and my goal is to find the best convex approximation $f$ to $g$ in $L_2$.
My first question is whether it somehow follows that f necessarily has to be piecewise linear again?
If not, then I feel like we will still have to assume that it is to be able to continue.
Now having established that, I wrote down the problem, calculated the integral and after a couple of steps you can see that it is a standard quadratic program which could be solved with any generic quadratic programming solver (e.g. qpsolvers in Python).
My question is if there is a better way to solve this than to use brute force. Is there some kind of algorithm that takes $g$ and convexifies the non-convex parts or something? Any tips or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Geometrically, I can't think of a reason which would necessitate any curvature. From some perspectives, the biconjugate is viewed as the closest convex under-approximation of $g$, although I think that's in an $L_{\infty}$ sense, not  in $L_{2}$. Existence of a biconjugate also would require existence of an affine minorant of $g$, which might not occur for a nonconvex function.
